# Core Data migration issue - selector error

Tags: core-data

I've added a new attribute to one of my entities, core data has migrated it and is loading the app fine, not showing the incompatible model error, but when it comes to using the new attribute i'm getting selector errors, i would assume since theres nothing there yet, how do i get it so that if theres no data it just shows an empty string.

I've tried

```
var string : String = "No value"

        if let d : NSDate = lastTaken
        {
            let hours : NSNumber = hoursBetween!
            let hoursAsSeconds : NSTimeInterval = hours.doubleValue * 3600
            let time : NSDate = d.dateByAddingTimeInterval(hoursAsSeconds)

            let formatter : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, HH:mm"
            formatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

            string = formatter.stringFromDate(time)
        }

        return string
```

but it still throws the selector error. lastTaken is the new attribute

Full error

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[M lastTaken]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x12dd11b30'

if i edit out the if section, then the app runs and shows the no value string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you updated the Core Data model but didn't update your custom subclass of `NSManagedObject`. Now you're trying to access `lastTaken`, but the class doesn't have a property with that name. Re-generate the subclass, or add the new property to the class by hand.

Comment: While that wasn't the issue, the new property was in the subclass, for some reason the property had been removed from the data model, re-added it and now its fine